# Program to integrate a user-input polynomial in C

Tags: c, integration, polynomials, numerical-integration, polynomial-math

So, I have a program that allows the user to choose different methods of integration, and it integrates the function defined at the top of the program. (Please ignore the midpoint rule for mow)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 10
#define f(x) (x + (1/x))


void midpointrule(double uplimit,double lowlimit,int interval)
{
    int i;
    double func1=0;
    double deltax = (uplimit - lowlimit)/interval;
    for(i=1; i<=interval; i++)
    {
        func1 =  pow(M_E,pow(deltax,2));
    }
    func1 = func1*deltax;
    printf("midpoint result = %lf\n", func1);
}

void trapezoidalrule(double uplimit, double lowlimit, int interval){
    double h, ifx = 0.0, i;
    h = fabs(uplimit - lowlimit) / interval;
    ifx = ifx + f(lowlimit) + f(uplimit);
    for (i = lowlimit+h; i < uplimit;){
        ifx = ifx + (2 * f(i));
        i = i + h;
    }
    ifx = ifx * h / 2;
    printf("\nThe integral of the equation using Trapezoidal Rule is %lf\n", ifx);
}

void simpsonsrule(double uplimit, double lowlimit, int interval){
    double h, ifx =0.0, i;
    h = fabs(uplimit - lowlimit)/interval;
    ifx = ifx + f(lowlimit) + f(uplimit);
    for (i=lowlimit+h; i<uplimit;){
        ifx = ifx + (2 * f(i));
        i = i + (2*h);
    }
    ifx = ifx * h / 3;
    printf("\nThe integral of the equation using Simpson's rule is %lf\n", ifx);
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    printf("***************** MENU *****************\n");
    printf("Please select a method of integration:\n");
    printf("\t 1. Midpoint Rule\n");
    printf("\t 2. Trapezoidal Rule\n");
    printf("\t 3. Simpson's Method\n");
    printf("\t 4. Exit\n");
    printf("CHOICE: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    printf("****************************************\n");

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: printf("You have chosen the Midpoint Rule.\n");
                double x,y;
                int z;
                printf("Enter the lower limit: ");
                scanf("%lf", &x);
                printf("\nEnter the upper limit: ");
                scanf("%lf", &y);
                printf("\nEnter the interval: ");
                scanf("%d", &z);
                midpointrule(x,y,z);
            break;
        case 2: printf("You have chosen the Trapezoidal Rule.\n");
                printf("Enter the lower limit: ");
                scanf("%lf", &x);
                printf("\nEnter the upper limit: ");
                scanf("%lf", &y);
                printf("\nEnter the interval: ");
                scanf("%d", &z);
                trapezoidalrule(x,y,z);
            break;
        case 3: printf("You have chosen Simpson's Method.\n");
                printf("Enter the lower limit: ");
                scanf("%lf", &x);
                printf("\nEnter the upper limit: ");
                scanf("%lf", &y);
                printf("\nEnter the interval: ");
                scanf("%d", &z);
                simpsonsrule(x,y,z);
            break;
        case 4: printf("Goodbye!\n");
            exit(0);
            break;
        default: printf("Invalid input, please enter again\n");
        break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I want to have it so that the user can input the coefficients and order of a polynomial, and then integrate. How could I do this? Any detailed help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been tearing my hair out over this for weeks.

Comment: Do you know how to define a structure? Can you define a structure with a number that specifies the number of coefficients and a pointer to coefficients? Do you know how to dynamically allocate memory? Can you write a function that takes two parameters, one the structure described above and two the value of the variable for the polynomial, and then evaluates the polynomial at that point? Do you know how to declare a function pointer? Can you rewrite `simpsonrule` and the other routines so they take a function pointer as a parameter and use that as the function to integrate?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Could you give me an example as to how this would work??

Comment: @MRD `for (i=lowlimit+h; i<uplimit;){` is prone to **not** function as desired when `i<uplimit` is just a little bit off due to floating point calculation issues. Better to use an integer loop `for (int n = 0; n < interval; n++){` and adjust the body of the loop to account for the new iterator.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I want to have it so that the user can input the coefficients and order of a polynomial, and then integrate.

- Ask for the order
- Form a [flexible member array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) (FMA).
- Ask for the various coefficients
- Integrate the polynomial.

---

```
// FMA
typedef struct {
  unsigned order;
  double coefficient[]
} polynomial;

// Pseudo code
unsigned order = get_unsigned("Enter order")

polynomial *p = malloc(sizeof *p + sizeof p->coefficient[0] * order)
// test result

for i from 0 to order-1
  p->coefficient[i] = get_double("Enter coefficient");
  
integrate(p, a, b)  // Use the polynomial

free(p) // Clean up when done.
```

---

Integrating polynomial is much like evaluating a polynomial at `x`.  (Try that first.)  but instead of *sum* of `pow(x,i) * coefficient[i]`, use *sum* of `pow(x,i+1) * coefficient[i] / (i + 1)`.  Simplifications exist.